# Run code only if for each loop doesn't find a match?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

What can I change with this code such that if no match is found in the objectList some code will run?

```
for (Object o : objectList) {
 if (o.someValue()).equals(o2.someValue())) {
        // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Maybe because its 4am but I feel like this should be a simple question that I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: Have a boolean flag which is either `true` (for found) or `false` (for not found) and check it's start after the loop.  You could also use streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `boolean` flag to keep track of whether or not a match has been found, something like this:

```
boolean match = false;
for (Object o : objectList) {
    if (o.someValue()).equals(o2.someValue())) {
        match true;
        break;       // no point in iterating further
    }
}

if (!match) {
    System.out.println("No match was found in the list.");
}
```

If you are using Java 8, then there is a one-liner you may use with streams:

```
boolean match = objectList.stream()
        .anyMatch(t -> t.someValue().equals(o2.someValue()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response this works wonderfully and I learnt something new with your other suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple boolean *flag*

```
boolean found = false;
for (Object o : objectList) {
   if (o.someValue()).equals(o2.someValue())) {
    // Do stuff
    found = true;
   }
}

if (!found) {
 //Do your stuff when it was not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the streams support, for example...

```
Object match = objectList.stream().filter(o -> o.someValue()).equals(o2.someValue())).orElse(null);
if (match == null) {
    // No matches...
}
```

> Initially I thought of something like this (or even to use anyMatch), but it seems that the OP wants to do something for each match (//Do stuff)

Okay, so you could use `anyMatch` to "peek" to see if there are "any" matches in the stream and make a decision based on it, for example...

```
List<String> objectList = new ArrayList<String>(5);
objectList.add("A");
objectList.add("B");
objectList.add("C");
objectList.add("D");
objectList.add("A");
objectList.add("E");
objectList.add("F");
objectList.add("A");
objectList.add("G");
objectList.add("H");
objectList.add("I");
objectList.add("J");
objectList.add("A");
objectList.add("K");
objectList.add("A");
objectList.add("M");

if (objectList.stream().anyMatch(o -> o.equals("A"))) {
    objectList.stream().filter(o -> o.equals("A")).forEach(o -> System.out.println(o));
} else {
    // No matches
}
```

Comment: Initially I thought of something like this (or even to use `anyMatch`), but it seems that the OP wants to do something for each match (`//Do stuff`)

Comment: Sure, then keep iterating through the steam